# How to pass value to pointer parameter C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

This is the sample code

```
void test(void *outputData)
{
   u8 *changeData;
   changeData[1] = 'T';
   changeData[2] = 'M';
}

void main()
{
   u8* const buf = (u8*) malloc(36654);
   test(buf);
}
```

So what I am trying to do is to return changedata to buf

I tried this in test function but it seem doesn't work

```
*outputData = *changeData
```

Edit:

I am trying to access the buf on main function that I have modified in test function

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably meant `u8 *changeData = outputData;`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: is memory for changeData allocated separately?

Comment: I put *outputData = *changeData below the changeData[1] = 'T', I tried your suggestion u8 *changeData = outputData; however when I try to print buf in main function, buf is empty

Comment: Post the code which is not working

Comment: I got it working with memcpy. Thanks guys. I think I saw one posted before, but i think it has been removed

Comment: @Adriansyah I removed my answer because it was down voted

Comment: My answer was more c based than c++, use whozcraig's answer. It is the proper method for C++

Comment: @Adriansyah Please do not edit your Question to include an answer.  Answers shoud be posted below in the answer box. You may either accept a posted answer, or post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry, I am new to this forum, I will write my answer in answer section. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments in code below. The list of things either wrong or ill-advised in your code are numerous. Admittedly, as your question post is not entirely clear, this is a best-guess proposal, but is probably close to what you seek. If not....

```
#include <iostream>

// not specified in your question code. assumed to come from somewhere
typedef unsigned char u8;

void test(void *outputData)
{
    // C allows implicit casting from void*; C++ does not.
    u8 *changeData = reinterpret_cast<u8*>(outputData);

    // C and C++ both use zero-based indexing for arrays of data
    changeData[0] = 'T';
    changeData[1] = 'M';
    changeData[2] = 0;
}

// void is not a standard supported return type from main()
int main()
{
    // in C++, use operator new, not malloc, unless you have
    //  a solid reason to do otherwise (and you don't)
    u8* const buf = new u8[3];
    test(buf);

    // display output
    std::cout << buf << '\n';

    // delete[] what you new[], delete what you new.
    delete[] buf;
}
```

Comment: Consider `u8 buf[3];`, or `vector<u8> buf(3);`  . Using new and delete is not really advisable these days

Comment: @MattMcNabb well yeah, sure. but I've no idea where the OP's *real* code is sourcing data from, and it was opportunistic to at least point toward `operator new` rather than `malloc`. Regardless, noted and upticked. Hope he sees your comment.

Comment: @MattMcNabb do you understand the const in the allocation? Or is this another part of the mystery?

Comment: @fingaz the pointer variable is const; not the pointed-to data. Thus the requirement for that initializer.

Comment: @fingaz Yes I do understand it. Some people like to write that to prevent accidentally making `buf` point elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference a void pointer. You need to change the input parameter type to `u8*`.

Comment: Hi, I try like you suggested, I change the parameter void to u8, However when I try to access the buf from main, it return only the first character, in this case, it only return 'T', and not 'M'. Sorry I just modify the question to include changeData[2]

Comment: Sorry what exactly are you trying to do? Maybe I'm not understanding your question..

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a pointer, the `*` is part of the type.

```
u8* x = nullptr;
```

This declares a pointer as a `nullptr`.  When you use the variable `x`, `*` dereferences the address.

```
u8* x = new u8;
*x = 'X';
```

So, `*` has different semantics in the declaration and with the variable.  When you use the variable `x`, it already has the type `u8*`.  So you don't want to dereference it when you assign a memory address.

```
x = nullptr;
```

So using this, your code with minimal changes, would look as follows...

```
void test(void *outputData)
{
   u8 *changeData = outputData;
   changeData[1] = 'T';
   changeData[2] = 'M';
}

void main()
{
   u8* const buf = (u8*) malloc(36654);
   test(buf);
}
```

Honestly, this neglects a number of other issues though.

Comment: What does this have to do with OP's question? What changes are you suggesting?

Comment: They updated the question a few times.  The code has more than one problem, but the major problem was incorrect pointer usage.  I'm suggesting fixing it.

Comment: So where does `x = nullptr;` go in OP's program?

Comment: I added possible example code changes.  It doesn't *need* `nullptr`, although it should be used when a pointer doesn't point to a valid address (e.g. is uninitialized).

Answer (score 0):

memcpy is also work for me. However WhozCraig answer is more appropriate and tidy for C++.